# Get new version of timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone, moment-timezone

i am having issue with time zone which i am getting older version of timezone like calcutta instead of kolkata

i have tried Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone and momentTz.tz.guess() but this both gives me older version of timezone

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `Asia/Kolkata` and `Asia/Calcutta` are equivalent, and there's no direct way to get one from the other from either `Intl` or Moment.  The accepted answer in the linked duplicate explains why.